# Why use custom Querysets instead of custom model Managers?

Tags: python, django, django-models

It seems like much of what can be done by a custom [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) can be accomplished by a model [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods). So why use custom Querysets instead of model Managers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom querysets allow for chaining methods, while custom managers only let you access defined methods directly from the manager. If you need to expose methods from the manager and the queryset, you can use `Queryset.as_manager`.

Take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#create-manager-with-queryset-methods